# javascript if else for beginners

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript, so I am having a hard time figuring out this easy exercise and what I'm doing this wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You are given two numeric variables: var n = 25; var result = 0;

Their values may change when you submit.
 DO NOT EDIT CODE ABOVE THIS LINE.
 =================================

Your Challenge:
 Using if and else, make decisions based on the values 
 of n and result with the following rules:
 1. When n is even, 
    set the value of result to result's current value 
    plus 10.
 2. When n is odd, 
    set the value of result to result's current value
    minus the value of n.
3. Do not declare new variables.
4. Be sure your solution works for all values of n and result.

```
if (n%2 == 0) {result+10;} else {result-n;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set the result?

```
if (n%2 == 0) {
    result = result + 10;
} else {
    result = result - n;
}
```

Or if you're a bit better:

```
 if (n % 2 == 0) {
    result += 10;
} else {
    result -=n;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Your problem isn't `if`/`else`, the problem is you never set `result` to the new value. `result+10` just results in the value without storing that value anywhere. (In many programming langauges, that would be a syntax error, but JavaScript allows what it calls *ExpressionStatement* where any expression can be a statement.)

Either use the compound assignment operators (`+=` and `-=`), or write a verbose assignment (`result = ...`).

---

Side note: It's easier to debug and edit code when statements are on their own lines, suggest:

```
if (condition) {
    trueStuffHere
} else {
    falseStuffHere
}
```

...or any of the several variations on that theme where `trueStuffHere` and `falseStuffHere` are on lines of their own.